# What is the meaning to line of code within this function?

Tags: python

One of the problems in my curriculum states to create a function that returns a copy of a list with the non-true elements removed. After reviewing the solution, I didn't understand the meaning of this line of code in the solution:

```
   [val for val in lst if val]
```

I understand loops and if statements, however this does not make sense to me. I have not been able to find anything within my curriculum about this or the internet. If anyone understands and can explain, I would appreciate it. The entire function solution is below

```
def compact(lst):
    """Return a copy of lst with non-true elements removed.

        >>> compact([0, 1, 2, '', [], False, (), None, 'All done'])
        [1, 2, 'All done']
    """

    return [val for val in lst if val]
```

Comment: What part do you not understand?  The comment tells you the overall effect.  List comprehensions are documented very well.  "Truthy" evaluation is documented very well.

Comment: The words are `ternary operator` and `list comprehension` if you want to read up on them.

Comment: Google "list comprehension", that's what it's called.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: @hippozhipos that's not a ternary expression.

Comment: Read about list comprehension. Just google it. In this case it append to list and return each element from the incoming list that match the condition - in this case when the element is True.

Comment: Note that Python has its own tutorial pages, this is the one which applies here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions (the proposed duplicate is practically a variant of it)

Comment: @Alex Hall Isn't the syntax "statement if condition else otherStatement" a ternary operator in python?

Comment: @hippozhipos Yes, and where do you see that in the OP's code?

Comment: @hippozhipos yes, and there's no `else` here.

Comment: I mean yh, but when i was learning if statements on the same line as statement, it didn't really make sense to me until i read what ternary operators are, so i though it would help him as well.

Comment: Thanks for help for those who did! Just needed some direction since it is my 3rd day into Python. Will look into list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_list = [val for val in lst if val]
```

Assigns a result to new_list using a `list comprehension` and is functionally equivalent to:

```
new_list = []
for val in lst:
    if val:
        new_list.append(val)
```

So all list elements, that are not `True` are filtered out.

You can find a good explanation about list comprehensions [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Comment: Thank you for the help! and the reference link.